# passing and returning a 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble passing in, editing, and then returning a 2D array from a function. I am trying using a pointer to do so, but cannot get the parameter types to be compatible.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double** get2DArray(double *info[3])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            if(i == j)
                info[i][j] = 0;

    double** out = info;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    double stuff[2][3] = {{1, 3, 5},{2, 4, 6}};
    double(*temp)[3] = stuff;

    double** info = get2DArray(temp);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            cout << info[i][j] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Built-in arrays difficult to use. If you can, use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Also, a 2d array is not the same as `T **`

Comment: You can pass an array to a function, however you cannot return it, because arrays aren't copyable nor assignable.

Comment: @101010 You cannot pass an array to a function (because they're uncopyable), you can only pass a pointer to one. Same applies for returning.

Comment: @zenith Sure you can, by reference.

Comment: @101010 Well, you can also return a reference to an array.

Comment: @zenith Sure you can, but what's the use of returning an object that is out of scope (if array is defined locally in the function), and if you're already passing it by reference what's the use to return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a 2D array and an array of pointers are two different beasts. A 2D array is just a single sequence. With `T arr[X][Y];` (where X and T are integer constants) `T[i][j]` is by definition `*(&(arr[0][0]) + i*Y + j)`.

But with an array of pointers `arr[i]` is a pointer, and you can write `arr[i] = new int[10];` which would cause an error with a 2D array.

If you want to see an `array[2][3]` (6 elements) as an `array[3][2]` (I cannot imagine a real use case for it, but it is what your code suggests), you could write:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double  (*get2DArray(double (*info)[2][3]))[2][3]
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            if(i == j)
                (*info)[i][j] = 0;

    double (* out)[2][3] = info;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    double stuff[2][3] = {{1, 3, 5},{2, 4, 6}};
    double (*temp)[2][3] = &stuff;

    double (*info)[3][2] = reinterpret_cast<double (*)[3][2]>(get2DArray(temp));

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            cout << (*info)[i][j] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an array through a function return call, due to the fact that arrays are not copyable nor are assignable.

However, you can pass an array into a function by reference. Hence, changing your `get2DArray` function to:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void get2DArray(double (&info)[N][M]) {
  // ...
}
```

You can pass an arbitrary dimensions 2d array by reference and change its contents as desired [**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56c7f6cd9aa33722).

Now if you want the change to take place on a copy of your original array (e.g., `stuff`), you could copy `stuff` into `temp` using `std::copy` and then pass `temp` to `get2DArray`:

```
double stuff[2][3] = {{1, 3, 5},{2, 4, 6}};
double temp[2][3];
std::copy(&stuff[0][0], &stuff[0][0] + 6, &temp[0][0]);
get2DArray(temp);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b895cc54cb140eb8)